# Encoding large numbers of categorical variables as input data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

One hot encoding doesn't sound like a great idea when you're dealing with hundreds of categories e.g. a data set where one of the columns is "first name". What's the best approach to go about encoding this sort of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the hashing trick:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing#Feature_vectorization_using_the_hashing_trick

It's cheap to compute, easy to use, allows you to specify the dimensionality, and often serves as a very good basis for classification.

For your specific application, I would hash feature-value pairs, like ('FirstName','John'), then increment the bucket for the hashed value.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large number of categories, Classification algorithm does not work well. Instead, there is a better approach of doing this. You apply regression algorithm on data and then train offset on those output. It would give you better results.

A sample code can be found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/realtwo/prudential-life-insurance-assessment/xgb-test/run/152209/code).