# how to do cross validation and hyper parameter tuning for huge dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I have a csv file of 10+gb ,i used "chunksize" parameter available in the pandas.read_csv() to read and pre-process the data,for training the model want to use one of the online learning algo.

normally  cross-validation and hyper-parameter tuning is done on the entire training data set and train the model using the best hyper-parameter,but in the case of the huge data, if i do the same on the chunk of the training data how to choose the hyper-parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for online learning algorithms like the ones mentioned on this link [Scaling Strategies for large datasets](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning). You should use algorithms that support `partial_fit` parameter to load these large datasets in chunks. You can also look at the following links to see which one helps you the best, since you haven't specified the exact problem or the algorithm that you are working on:

- [Numpy save partial results in RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149803/working-with-big-data-in-python-and-numpy-not-enough-ram-how-to-save-partial-r?lq=1)
- [Scalling Computationally - Sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#strategies-to-scale-computationally-bigger-data)
- [Using Large Datasets in Sklearn](https://opendatascience.com/blog/riding-on-large-data-with-scikit-learn/)
- [Comparision of various Online Sovers -Sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sgd_comparison.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-sgd-comparison-py)

**EDIT** : If you want to solve the class imbalance problem, you can try this : [imabalanced-learn library in Python](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn)

Comment: i wanted to use algorithms MLPClassifier or SGD,my problem is how to tune the hyper-parameter in the online learning algorithm,i cannot use the grid search for each and every chunk ryt?

Comment: @ashwing gridSearchCV and the online implementation of SGD will take care of that itself, you don't need to tune each and every parameter manually. Read more about it here : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

Comment: when i am dummifing each chunk of data over iteration and train the model ,few levels in the categorical variables are missing because they are appear in the later part of the file ....is there any solution for this?

Comment: @ashwing you can try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35411686/8160718